# Angular - indexOf JS not working into *ngIf

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have the following HTML code, using Angular. I need to check mimetype of file before display it, specific display for image and pdf.

I try this :

```
<span *ngFor='let media of tabMedia; let ind = index'>
    <span *ngIf="media['mimetype'].indexOf('image') > -1">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
            <a (click)="openModal('image_' + ind)" style="cursor: pointer">
                <img [id]="'image_' + ind" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" [src]="'data:' + media['mimetype'] + ';base64,' + media.file" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
    </span>
</span>
```

But I have the following error :

```
ERROR TypeError: "_v.context.$implicit.mimetype.indexOf is not a function"
```

I tried also with `media['mimetype'].includes('image')` and I have the same error

How could I check the mime type and display different HTML for each mimetype ?

Thanks

Comment: What is media property ?

Comment: I updated the code. tabMedia is an array containing base64 of the file and mimetype

Comment: Could you please share ts file? What is tabMedia object? What is its properties?

Answer (score 0):

do like this.

```
<span *ngIf="checkMime()">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
        <a (click)="openModal('image_' + ind)" style="cursor: pointer">
            <img [id]="'image_' + ind" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" [src]="'data:' + media['mimetype'] + ';base64,' + media.file" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
</span>
```

then in component

```
checkMime(){
    return media['mimetype'].indexOf('image') > -1;
}
```

let me know if you have doubt.